# mod_rewrite module in Apache

Tags: php, apache

i read mod_rewrite module installed in my Apache server! to implement clean url. My apache server is 2.0. I can't see this module in my php info. How i install this module. Does any one tell me ?

Comment: Consider moving this to http://serverfault.com/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the httpd.conf file uncomment the line LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so (remove the pound '#' sign from in front of the line)

that is the basic way, usually new version of apache has uncomment this.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to enable it using `a2enmod rewrite` followed by a restart or reload of Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If your using php as **CGI** you won't see mod_rewrite in phpinfo().
(Or other apache modules for that matter.)