# Adding rewrite rules to .htaccess gives server error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp, internal-server-error

I have added the following lines to my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.css$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^http://127.0.0.1(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1/getcss.php?$1/$2 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*site-cookie=([^;]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^http://127.0.0.1(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1/cloked.php?$1/$2 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{http_COOKIE} ^.*site-cookie=!([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ htp://127.0.0.1/noaccess.php?$1 [NC]
```

It gives me *"index.php"*. This is a WAMP installation with Apache 2.2.11(win) - php 5.3.0.

Comment: Look into the `error.log` file to see what the error is.

Comment: You write `${htp_COOKIE}`, is that intentional?

Comment: @pekka: error log says :.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine',

Comment: @jan: thanks - fixed that but error still persists!

Comment: @tnt: Do you have the `mod_rewrite` module enabled in your Apache configuration?

Comment: @tnt see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847250/mod-rewrite-module-in-apache

Comment: @jan - ummm. excuse my ignorance; im using wamp server 2.0. if i list the modules there is no reference to mod_rewrite. Ahh found it rewrite_module :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use rewrite rules, you need to enable [the rewrite module of Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/). How to do this depends on which installation of Apache you use. Wamp allows you to do this via the configuration menu.

Comment: Thanks Jan, the module is installed and enabled. However my .htaccess seems to have no effect.